# How to work with two repeaters in asp

Tags: c#, asp.net, repeater

I have a menu that I'm making with a repeater in asp and the first row of the menu is working and I want to add drop down options in the menu with the second repeater but from the class I don't have access to `Repeater2`.

```
<asp:Repeater id="Repeater1"  runat="server" >
   <itemtemplate runat="server">
       <ul class="rmenue" runat="server">
           <li><a>
               <asp:Label  runat="server"  ID="Label1" 
                    text='<%# Eval("_name") %>' CommandArgument='<%# Eval("_url") %>' />

               <asp:Repeater id="Repeater2"  runat="server" >
                  <itemtemplate runat="server">
                     <ul class="menue" runat="server">
                        <li><a>
                           <asp:Label  runat="server"  ID="Label2" 
                                  text='<%# Eval("_name") %>' CommandArgument='<%# Eval("_url") %>' />
                        </a></li> 
                      </ul>
                   </itemtemplate>
               </asp:Repeater>
           </a></li> 
       </ul>
    </itemtemplate>
 </asp:Repeater>


public partial class Master : System.Web.UI.MasterPage
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        List<Buttons> ds = new List<Buttons>();
        ds.Add(new Buttons("Home", "blahbla"));
        ds.Add(new Buttons("ACCOUNTS", "blahbla"));
        ds.Add(new Buttons("ACCOUNTS", "blahbla"));
        ds.Add(new Buttons("PLAT", "blahbla"));
        ds.Add(new Buttons("EDU", "blahbla"));
        ds.Add(new Buttons("ABOUT", "blahbla"));
        ds.Add(new Buttons("CONTACT US", "blahbla"));


        Repeater1.DataSource = ds;
        Repeater1.DataBind();
    }
}
public class Buttons
{

    public string _name { get; set; }
    public string _url { get; set; }
    public ArrayList<Buttons> drop = new ArrayList<Buttons>();\\this is the data for the second repeater
    public Buttons() { }
    public Buttons(string name,string url) {
        this._name = name;
        this._url = url;
    }

}
```

Comment: Why not use asp:DropDownList control ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this but you need to do it in the code behind.

In your 1st Repeater you need an `OnItemDataBound` event; `OnItemDataBound="Repeater1_ItemDataBound"`

In the codebehind:

```
protected void Repeater1_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
    {
        var repeater2 = (Repeater)e.Item.FindControl("Repeater2");
        //now you can bind etc to repeater2
    }
}
```

Comment: yesss this works but it gives me the same option for all the dropDowns .
is there another way to have diffrint option for each option on the main menu ? or with the way im doing it there isn't ?

Comment: Each repeater item has the same controls yet these are entirely separate from the previous or next iteration. And because you have them nested, if you give Repeater2 the same datasource, so every iteration of Repeater1 it's going to simply spit out the same contents.